# Xamarin iOS getting data from a URL is always null with Azure Blob Storage URL

Tags: ios, azure, xamarin, azure-blob-storage

So I'm using this code to get an image from a url:

```
using (var url = new NSUrl(_img))
            using (var data = NSData.FromUrl(url))
            {
                scrollView = new UIScrollView(new CGRect(0, 0, View.Frame.Width, View.Frame.Height));
                View.AddSubview(scrollView);
                imageView = new UIImageView(UIImage.LoadFromData(data));
                //imgLoanDocument.SizeToFit();
                scrollView.ContentSize = imageView.Image.Size;
                scrollView.AddSubview (imageView);
                scrollView.Scrolled += DidScroll;
            }
```

This works just fine if I grab any random image from the web.

However, if I try to use the URL of one of my blobs in an Azure Blob Storage account that I construct via an API call, which looks like this:

```
http://myazureaccount.blob.core.windows.net/cd8ce230-715e-473d-9c08-98221691c96e/a15de7d3-0947-41fc-b5b3-6dc45d8f42fe?sv=2015-12-11&sr=b&sig=2skZ9e6iJWprRQX2Zmff%2BwfivgXS903aaBYZFUaNH1I%3D&st=2017-04-11T03%3A05%3A53Z&se=2017-04-11T03%3A30%3A53Z&sp=r
```

then `data` in `var data = NSData.FromUrl(url)` is always null. I can take this exact same URL and text it to myself and view the image just fine(I even get a preview in iOS message app). If I enter this URL into the browser it automatically downloads, and if I view the URL using Chrome's inspector I see a preview of the image.

I even added a plist key for using non-https URLs:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```

Anyone have any ideas?

***UPDATE***:

So looking at the simulate logs, I see this:

```
App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.
```

But shouldn't the above plist entry resolve this error?

Comment: Watch the device/simulator log when you make that request for errors. The number one thing would be an ATS issue, can you can add the `<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>` that you added to your `info.plist` to your question

Comment: Can you share the actual URL of the blob?

Comment: @GauravMantri Unfortunately I can't share the url.

Comment: @SushiHangover let me try that and see what happens

Comment: @James Manually delete the app from the device/simulator and do a Clean and then rebuild the app just to make sure that your info.plist changes are being picked up.

Comment: @SushiHangover amazing! Clean and rebuild and deleting the app worked! If you want to create an actual answer to this question I will accept! Thank you :)